# Wifi problem in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, ubuntu-drivers

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 onto my 10 year old laptop , so first worked perfectly fine , i was very pleased,
but then say 5 minutes after connecting my WiFi (my mobile hotspot) i was getting problem with the WiFi first it started showing the "?" on the WiFi symbol and it when i tried reconnecting i got a error saying "Activation of network connection failed"
This is happening every time i connect to WiFi , i tried connecting to other hotspots,
What should i do i just cannot connect to internet in my laptop

EDIT: information about my WiFi card :

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
DeviceName: WLAN
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
```

Edit:

```
$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list`

Comment: this is the output :   ...
$ rfkill list   ...
0: phy0: Wireless LAN    ...
 Soft blocked: no    .... 
 Hard blocked: no